# Dataframe writing on parquet taking too long (boto3 library and Glue AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue, parquet

I have a query that runs perfectly in Athena, but when I use this query in Glue Job (with library python boto3), I can't write the query result to the parquet because of its execution time.

If I set a limit of up to 5,000 lines, it writes very fast, but when I increase that limit, it takes at least ten times as long. The total number of records it should write is less than 200k lines.  Are there any parameters or details I need to specify in order to get good performance when writing to parquet?

```py
df.repartition(5)\
.write\
.mode("overwrite")\
.partitionBy('year')\
.parquet(f" s3_path")
```

I tried to put the parameter below and I see no difference.

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "300")
```